# How to find how "related" items are in a list of lists?

Tags: math, multidimensional-array, graph, graph-theory

I have an idea of what I'm looking for, but I have no idea what the mathematical term is and where to look.

Consider the following list of lists:

```
[
["Apple","Banana","Carrot"],
["Banana","Carrot","Dates"],
["Apple", "Banana"],
]
```

I want to find out how "related" each of the items (Apple, Banana, Carrot, Dates) are, based on how frequently they appear in groups together.

So for example, I can say Apples and Bananas are highly "related" because "Banana" appeared 100% of the time that "Apple" appeared in a list. Likewise, "Apple" appeared 66.7% of the time that "Banana" appeared in a list." I can say "Dates" and "Apple" have no relationship, because anytime one appeared, the other didn't.

What am I measuring here? Is there a better way to measure how "related" items are?

Also, based on the Apple/Banana example, it's clear that my measure of "relatedness" doesn't have the symmetric property (Apple is 100% related to Banana, but Banana is only 66.7% related to Apple). I think that's fine for what I ultimately want to do, but I would be curious if there is a measure that does have the symmetric property.

Thanks.

Comment: " Is there a better way to measure how "related" items are?"  The only way to answer your question would be if you told us what you wanted the measure for.

Comment: " I think that's fine for what I ultimately want to do".  So then it is OK.  But only you can know because you have given us no idea what it is you want to do.

Comment: Maybe [the apriori algorithm](https://towardsdatascience.com/the-apriori-algorithm-5da3db9aea95)?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Odds_ratio sounds like it might be a useful concept to read up on.